# check void pointer size in macro c

Tags: c, pointers, visual-studio-2008, macros, windows-xp

I need to check if void pointer fits in 8 bytes, so i check if its length is 4 or 8. I know these values are only, i can use `_W64`, just a curious check.

```
#include <windows.h>
#if (sizeof(void *) == 4)
#define IS64 0
#elif (sizeof(void *) == 8)
#define IS64 1
#else
#error "Pointer size 4 nor 8, make changes in app"
#endif
int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
        HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
        LPTSTR    lpCmdLine, 
        int       cmdShow)
{
    if (IS64) MessageBoxA(NULL, "is 64", "info", MB_OK);
    else MessageBoxA(NULL, "is 32", "info", MB_OK);
    return(0);
}
```

This code does not work, i got an error `app.c(2) : fatal error C1017: invalid integer constant expression`

I changed macro to:

```
#if (sizeof(void *) == sizeof(int32_t))
#define IS64 0
#elif (sizeof(void *) == sizeof(int64_t))
#define IS64 1
#else
#error "Pointer size 4 nor 8, make changes in app"
#endif
```

Same error. Any workarounds here?

Comment: `#define IS64 (sizeof(void*)==8)`

Comment: @WhozCraig that's a good Macro and a good workaround. I suspect that he wanted a preprocessor conditional expression, that it's not allowed as sizeof cannot be obviously understood by the preprocessor.

Comment: @Jekyll certainly, and thus it is in comment and not an answer. I don't understand why he isn't just using the MS-predefineds, but I'm sure there is a reason. Oh wait, he said he is, was just curious why this didn't work. nm =P

Comment: @WhozCraig so my comment was actually the answer? Also I wasn't sure what he wanted to achieve

Comment: I decided to use `#define IS64 (if(sizeof(void*)==4) ? 0 : (if(sizeof(void*)==8) ? 1 : exit(1) /*Or some message box*/))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of `sizeof` operator isn't valid in the macros because it isn't part of cpp, it's part of the C language. But you still can put this check at compile-time without extra cost because a good compiler will remove such a dead code. In fact, it's recommend by some coding standard.

**EDIT:** To leave this test to the compile you need to something like this:

```
int IS64;
if (sizeof(void *) == 4)
 IS64  = 0;
else if (sizeof(void *) == 8)
 IS64 = 1;
else
printf ("Pointer size 4 nor 8, make changes in app\n");
```

and then:

```
   if (IS64) MessageBoxA(NULL, "is 64", "info", MB_OK);
    else MessageBoxA(NULL, "is 32", "info", MB_OK);
```

A good compiler will remove the dead code, i.e., returned value of `sizeof()` (if not used in VLA) is always a constant value and depeding if it's `4` or `8` and compiler you're doing `4 == 4` or `8 == 8` or `8 == 4` it will perform [**DCE**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination) and you will have only `MessageBoxA()` in your program without the `if (IS64)` check.

Comment: That's only partially true. The preprocessor provides *type-generic macros*, which *are* somehow language-aware.

Comment: Are you speaking about C11's `_Generic()`? I didn't know about before.

Comment: My code does also not works, if i tell compiler to compile it as c code.

Comment: On second thought, I think you're completely right and the preprocessor is unconnected to the C language -- the type-generic code is part of the C language (provided by the `_Generic` keyword), and the preprocessor doesn't see any of it.

Answer (score 3):

**GCC** comes with a bunch of preprocessor defines;

to address this specific problem, it provides `__SIZEOF_POINTER__` whose value is 8 or 4 depending on the architecture.

I'm not an expert of the *MS compilers*, but I guess they provides equivalent defines;

A rapid search on the argument *(source: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2019)* shows the followings:

> **_M_AMD64** Defined as the integer literal value 100 for compilations that target x64 processors. Otherwise, undefined.
>
> **_M_ARM** Defined as the integer literal value 7 for compilations that target ARM processors. Otherwise, undefined.
>
> **_M_ARM_ARMV7VE** Defined as 1 when the /arch:ARMv7VE compiler option is set for compilations that target ARM processors. Otherwise,
>   undefined.
>
> **_M_ARM_FP** Defined as an integer literal value that indicates which /arch compiler option was set for ARM processor targets. Otherwise,
>   undefined.
>
> **_M_ARM64** Defined as 1 for compilations that target 64-bit ARM processors. Otherwise, undefined.

Using these information you may assign a value to your define.